# How to make a div overlay when child tag is added

Tags: javascript, css, paypal, dom-events

I am using Paypal zoid and I have a button that when clicked, iframe is opened in the parent div, however, this iframe pushes the other contents of the web making the web look ugly, I was wondering if there is a way to make the parent div wait for the iframe to enter then it is styled as overlay and when the iframe is closed then it goes back to its position?

I will really appreciate someone helping me, a simple code will help or if zoid has a way to make iframe overlay the web content then it will be even better
my divs looks like this:

```
<script src='zoid_sett.js'></script>
<div id='zoid_iframe'>
    <!--the iframe appears here -->
</div>
<div id="zoid_btn">
<script>
  mybutton({}).render('#zoid_btn')
<script>
</div>
```

The iframe dimensions are 500 by 300 which is set in zoid settings.js file I am including.
My issue is not with the zoid render of the iframe but rather the styling of the iframe or the iframe's parent div to be an overlay.

Comment: We can't help you fix code we can't see. Add your current code to the question and explain the specific problem you're having.

Comment: thanks mobeen for the comment i added code

Answer (score 0):

You could use an overlay wrapper to be positioned as fixed.

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div id='zoid_iframe'>
    <div>Loading iframe here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: flex;
}

#overlay #zoid_iframe {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

#overlay #zoid_iframe div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Just connect the button to "show" the overlay.
You can also add a "close" button to "hide" the overlay.

This is how it could look like when you "activate" the overlay.
https://jsfiddle.net/3q1yhro5/1/

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks medda86, the issue is, the button is also in an iframe so it cannot modify the script in the parent window or is there a way?

Comment: @kim you might be able to put the iframe as fixed too till you close the iframe, but I dont think you can listen to the click events inside iframe. You might however be able to listen to click on iframe. But I'm afraid you wount be able to know if the user is clicking the button inside the iframe.